# ViewPager Scroll issue on soft keyboard open

Tags: android, android-viewpager, scrollview, android-softkeyboard

This is my activity layout :

MainActivity:

```
  <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/sky_blue"
    android:elevation="@dimen/elevation_depth"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    app:titleTextAppearance="?attr/titleTextAppearance">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/toolbar_title_font_size"/>

 </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

 <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/details_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/text_size_12"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:elevation="@dimen/elevation_depth"
            android:paddingBottom="20dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Something"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_18"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_address"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/text_name"
                android:text="J P Nagar, Bangalote - 560012"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_amount"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/text_address"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:text="Total Amount :"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_amount_value"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/text_amount"
                android:text="1000"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_18"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/text_amount"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/text_amount_value"
                android:text="@string/rupee_symbol"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_18"/>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:isScrollContainer="false"
            android:layout_below="@+id/details_layout"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/text_size_12"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/text_size_12"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/text_size_12"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:elevation="@dimen/elevation_depth"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/payment_tab_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:elevation="2dp"
                app:tabGravity="fill"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/sky_blue"
                app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/sky_blue"
                app:tabTextAppearance="@style/tab_layout_font_style"
                app:tabTextColor="@color/sky_blue_light"/>

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/payment_viewpager"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:isScrollContainer="false"
                android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
                android:padding="@dimen/text_size_12"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

      </LinearLayout>
   </ScrollView>
  </RelativeLayout>
```

ViewPager loads different fragment, and some fragment contains edit text. My problem is that, on click of edit text screen is resizing only inside viewPager fragment not complete activity. If I use adjust pan my toolbar is moving out of the view and on using adjustResize view pager contents are only moving. I want my toolbar should be fixed and content in my main activity should resize.

Hoping for quick solution..

Comment: What exactly your current screen showing ? Can u post reference screen.

Comment: screen looks fine, but on keyboard popup it is not resizing parent layout

Comment: Please post current screen shot of that output i mean while keyboard pops up.